# JList not showing as a list, just a dot...maybe a graphic dot?

Tags: java, swing, generics, jlist

Trying to list the nodes in a JList so I can choose one from the list.

I have this code (and a lot more)...

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JLabel flabel = new JLabel("Förbindelse från " + n1 +" till " + n2, JLabel.CENTER);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(JLista);
DefaultListModel<Edge<Node>> Jlistan = new DefaultListModel<Edge<Node>>();

List<Edge<Node>> listan = listGraph.getEdgesBetween(n1,n2);
for (Edge<Node> listEdge : listan) {
Jlistan.addElement(listEdge);
}

JLista = new JList<Edge<Node>> (Jlistan);
JLista.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
JLista.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
JLista.setVisibleRowCount(5);
JLista.setSize(100, 100);
getJlistVal();

row2.add(scroll);
row1.add(flabel);
add(row1);
add(row2);
}
```

...

```
public Edge<Node> getJlistVal(){
return JLista.getSelectedValue();
}
```

But when listing, i just get a little spot on the Jpanel, i think its a graphical dot, or a very very litte Jlist. :( cant publish a picture yet...

1. I thought it had to do with pixelsize but dont think so??
2. Do i *have* to specify size of the list??
3. The list to be displayed is a generic LIST as type Node. I have a method that i call, is the return type ok?

//thank you

-Help me StackOverflow.  You are my only hope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create scroll instance with null list.

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(JLista);
```

Just move the line after

```
JLista = new JList<Edge<Node>> (Jlistan);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing wrong because your example won't compile without your other classes, But When I use the above code, adding in a bit of my own, it works. The only difference is I used a `Box` instead of `BoxLayout`, which is pretty much the same thing, just a `Box` uses a `JPanel` under the hood. I had to do this because it wasn't allowing be to use `this` from the `JFrame` subclass. You can test it

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author Paul SamSotha
 */
public class TestList extends JFrame {

    public TestList() {
        String[] list = {"Hello", "Jello", "Wello"};
        JList JLista = new JList(list);

        JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel flabel = new JLabel("Förbindelse från ", JLabel.CENTER);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(JLista);

        JLista.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JLista.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
        JLista.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        JLista.setSize(100, 100);


        row2.add(scroll);
        row1.add(flabel);
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box.add(row1);
        box.add(row2);

        add(box);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new TestList();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

---

> "Do i have to specify size of the list??"

No, you can just call `.pack()` on the frame and let the pack do its magic

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, get the value in the `getJlistVal()` and return the value as a `String`.

`String selected = jList1.getSelectedItem().toString();`

and try to return that value. Tell me if it prints. I can't test it myself right now. 
Just a suggestion to try, let me know how it goes.

Currently what your method `getJListVal()` is doing is, returning the value as an Element. Which may be your problem. Try returning it as a String, int or generic variable type, then try displaying it.